# accessing nodes/leafs in a tree

Tags: sml, smlnj

Im doing a homework problem in Standard ML which we just started learning, and im stuck trying to computer the sum of the leafs in a tree. How could i access the elements in the node of this tree?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You deconstruct complex data types through pattern matching. Most of the time, you do this in your function arguments. If your function `f` takes a list as an argument, instead of defining it as

```
fun f X = ...
```

you'd say

```
fun f x::xs = ...
```

Now, when you pass it a list, it will automatically assign `x` to the first element, and `xs` to the remainder.

In your case, it's going to look something like this:

```
fun sum Node(element,children)::siblings = ...
```